# How to get primary and secondary DNS servers in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, dns, qt5

I have configured on a Windows machine primary DNS server = 8.8.8.8 and secondary DNS server = 8.8.4.4. How can I find these addresses using Qt?

Comment: Do you need names?

Comment: Just IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Qt functionality to doing this. You need to use your OS specific API to do this. 
For linux you can read `/etc/resolv.conf` file or do check IPs with `sockets` programming.

On Windows you can use [GetAdapterAdresses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) <- C++ example code included